# how to make div background image responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**How to make this image responsive**

HTML:

```
<section id="first" class="story" data-speed="8" data-type="background">
    <div class="smashinglogo" id="welcomeimg" data-type="sprite" data-offsetY="100" data-Xposition="50%" data-speed="-2"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#first .smashinglogo {background: url(../images/logo1.png)  50% 100px no-repeat fixed;}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `background-size` property to the value of `100% auto` to achieve what you are looking for.

**For Instance,**

```
#first .smashinglogo{
   background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Hope this helps.

***PS:** As per your code above, you can remove `fixed` and add `100% auto` to achieve the output.*

Comment: For this answer image is using 100% area (too big) obviously. 
BTW Thank you for trying

Comment: This shall make your image to stretch responsively accordingly. If you find 100% to be too big, set a percentage value that is ideal for your needs. Then stretch it and check the output again. If it still does not work, use `background-size:100% auto;` - @Phoenix

Comment: How would you make the DIV be the same height as the background image?

Answer (score 7):

Try adding `background-size:cover`

```
.smashinglogo {background: url(../images/logo1.png)  50% 100px no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height:600px
}
```

Check [**this tutorial**](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-backgrounds/) for detailed article.

Comment: background Image disappeared.

Comment: The page "this tutorial" does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
background-size:100% auto;
```

or

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fixed Use

> max-width:100%;

this will work.

Final Output

```
.smashinglogo {
  background: url(../images/logo1.png)  50% 100px no-repeat;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#first .smashinglogo{
 background-image: url(../images/logo1.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

try this, it might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Making a Responsive image there are many ways.

The Basic rule is use `%` value instead of `pixel` value. and second is use `@media queries` to target the mobile devices and tablets.

Also you can use CSS3 new technique to make the image responsive:

```
.img-element: {url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

you can read more about Responsive image by clicking on this link. 
http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/

Answer (score 1):

I'm just summarising with an answer that helped me along the same lines.

```
.smashinglogo {
  max-width: 100%;
background-size:100% auto;
}

.smashinglogo {
  max-width: 100%;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Both the codes above worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

If you div background-image disappears when stacked on small devices (typically below 577px in width), then add "min-height:310px;" to your css.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to use the `min` operator within CSS:

```css
.smashinglogo {
    width: min(80vw, 800px);
    height: min(20vw, 200px);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: url(image.png) center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: min(80vw, 800px), min(20vw, 200px);
}
```

In that case, my image was of size 800px by 200px and I wanted it to scale responsively (at 80% of the full browser window width in this example) but not be larger than the original size.

The same should work for the `max` operator if one wants to have a lower limit in background image size.