# Image not fitting div size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set image on the right of the div. But somehow the image is not fitting in the div.
HTML:

```
            <div class="container" >
                <div class= "row list-container">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                <h3>This contains some description</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2" >
                    <img src = "img/Websitebackground.jpg" class = "img-responsive">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- /.container -->
```

CSS:

```
    #list-section{
    background:white;
    margin-top:100px;
    }
    .list-container{
        margin:20px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);

    }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sakib_rahman_cse11/czLvkr7z/

What I want is something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aov1M.jpg

Comment: I don't get what the outcome should be. Please clarify

Comment: What do you mean "set image on the right of the div" - like this? https://jsfiddle.net/czLvkr7z/1/ Or do you want the text beside the image with the text on the left and image on the right?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use bootstrap classes without bootstrap?

Comment: Explain a bit more mate

Comment: I want something like this 
http://imgur.com/a/x8lXs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Responsive Tags**

I have used col-xs-* instead of col-md-* and it all works

```
    <div class="container" >
                <div class= "row list-container">
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                <h3>This contains some description</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding:0 !important; margin: 0 !important">
                    <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/TpVSw4X.jpg" >
                </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- /.container -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sakib_rahman_cse11/czLvkr7z/

Answer (score 0):

If I truly understand you...

Images have default property `display: inline-block;` And this cause a `5px` white space under the image. If you want to remove this `5px` space, set this:

```
.img-responsive { display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this look like something you tried to achieve?
You can play around with width and height (absolute or relative), but the main Idea is that you use `background-image` instead of `<img>` tag, and use   `background-size:100% auto;` to make it responsive as described 
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006587/how-to-make-div-background-image-responsive) .

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    html, body, .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .desc-bg-div {
        height: 20%;        
        background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/TpVSw4X.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    .opaque-div {   
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        color: #ffffff;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" >                
        <div class="row outer">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                    <p>your content goes here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 desc-bg-div">              
                <div class="opaque-div">
                    <h3 class="description">This contains some description</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```