# How to make background of a div responsive?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a container that positioned horizontally in the middle of the body, this container includes a div inside of it, this div has a background, 
I want the background of the div to be responsive when shrinking or resizing the window like this site here [ask.fm](https://ask.fm/MohammadJarrar5) , I have used `background-size: cover;` but it didn't work with me.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 851px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.cover {
  background-image: url("wall.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
  .cover {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `background-size: contain;`

Comment: What do you mean `background-size: cover` didn't work for you? What happened and what were you expecting? Are you wanting the entire image to be visible?

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes i reviewed another answers for the same issue and they told to use background-size:cover

Comment: @LeonFreire unfortunately didn't work also :(

Comment: @MichaelCoker has some helpful questions. You should answer them Moawya. : )

Comment: @Moawyahks **what do you mean it didn't work for you. What happened and what were you expecting to happen instead?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make div background image responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006587/how-to-make-div-background-image-responsive)

Comment: @MichaelCoker I think yes i need the entire image to be visible when resizing the div , and i have expected by using background-size:cover to help me out .

Comment: @Moawyahks what are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: @MichaelCoker 840 X 300

Comment: So, you want an image to always be completely visible no matter what shape it's parent is... That's not possible with a background image.

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmGwzp

Comment: @MichaelCoker i need the full height of the image also , like this site here https://ask.fm/MohammadJarrar5

Comment: "full height of the image also" - what does that mean? The background at the top of ask.fm doesn't show the entire image all of the time. It scales and moves around inside of the fixed height container.

Comment: @MichaelCoker how can i achieve that instead of background image ??
to be like this site exactly https://ask.fm/MohammadJarrar5
you can see how the entire cover photo is visible here when resizing

Comment: Its not logical to think an image will always be completely visible and in proportion independent of the parent's size. :/

Comment: @Moawyahks on ask.fm, the entire photo is **not visible** when you resize. It crops the image and cuts off the left/right/bottom edges as you resize.

Comment: @LeonFreire how could that achieved here https://ask.fm/MohammadJarrar5 plz ?

Comment: @MichaelCoker if i would to do the same , can you help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do a combination of these 2 things - depending on screen size - and I grab different src for the image / background or inline depends...

```
<section class="container">
<div class="inner-w">

  <figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1600x900" alt="">
  </figure>

</div>
</section>



<section class="container section-name">
<div class="inner-w">

  <!-- ... -->

</div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/4j2avj7v/

```
figure {
  margin: 0;
}

figure img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container .inner-w {
  max-width: 400px; /* just for this example... likely 900+ */
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

.section-name .inner-w {
  min-height: 300px; /* it needs to have some shape */

  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1600x900');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Get acquainted with Chrome's dev tools, and then you can inspect websites you like and see how they wrote their CSS. The last.fm example you gave used background-size: cover;  Here's a little intro: https://egghead.io/lessons/misc-chrome-devtools-elements-inspect-elements-vs-view-source  : )