# Make responsive on a div element with a background image, no javascripts

Tags: html, css

Other options make background image adapt to its div element when resizing of window screen for responsive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make div background image responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006587/how-to-make-div-background-image-responsive)

Answer (score 2):

Simple as that:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this property it will work for you :-)

```
background-size: cover;
```